# Lambda event.body object from browser POST response is of different type

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

When I `console.log(event.body)` and perform a POST request by submitting a classical HTML form from the browser through AWS API Gateway->Lambda I get something like a query string:

```
event.body = 'first_name=Blabla&last_name=OOOOO&email=oooo%40aaa.com'
```

when running the same function via serverless-offline plugin on my localhost I get:

```
event.body = '{"first_name":"Blabla","last_name":"OOOOO","email":"oooo@aaa.com"}'
```

which looks like a JSON string.

I used same Node.js version (4.3.2).

Why is there this difference?

Comment: show us how you defined your method integration. what happens when you test via api gateway console? To find out exactly what is being sent to Lambda, look for "method request after transformation" (or sth like that)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the request mapping template is defined. In API GW console testing, please check the CW logs to see what is sent from API GW to Lambda under "Endpoint request body after transformations".